# UiDevice takeScreenshot not saving

Tags: android, testing, uidevice

I am attempting to take a screenshot of the emulator, but I am unable to save to photo.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ScreenshotTest : ScreenCaptureListener {
    private var device: UiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
@get:Rule
    var mRuntimePermissionRule = grant(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
@get:Rule
    var activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java , true)

@Test
    fun testScreenshot(){
        var directory = File("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Screenshot_Pics", "pic.png")
        device.takeScreenshot(directory)
    }
```

This is effectively my code, and the manifest file also contains these lines:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am unsure the main cause of this issue. I am guessing it has to do with the permissions because I think I have tried most other possible like setting my emulators graphics to use my computer's.